# Rust Setting static lifetime after initialization

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime

I have a graph struct which looks like this:

```
pub struct Graph {
   pub nodes: Vec<Node>,
   pub edges: Vec<Edge>
}
```

My program reads the nodes and edges from an external file and after that they will not be changed anymore.

How can i set the Graph to have a static lifetime so i can use it in multiple threads?

Comment: If your graph is only set once and you really really need the static lifetime, I recommend using [lazy_static!](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs) for this. But from a first glance, it seems to me like you don't really need a static lifetime. Instead, try wrapping your graph in an  `Arc<RwLock<Graph>>` and passing copies of it to the threads.

Comment: Is the external file known at compile time? If so, you could try to incorporate the construction of your `Graph` into `build.rs`.